# Assign and re-use quantile-based buckets by group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### What I am trying to achieve

I have a pandas DataFrame in a long format, containing values for different groups. I want to compute and apply a quantile based-binning (e.g. quintiles in this example) to each group of the DataFrame.

I also need to be able to keep the bins edges for each group and apply the same labelling (via `pd.cut`) to a new DataFrame.

E.g. for each of group, find the quintiles and assign them to a new column `value_label`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"group": "A", "val": np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=5, size=100)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"group": "B", "val": np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=3, size=100)})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

# apply qcut
labels_and_bins = df.groupby("group")["val"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q=5, duplicates="drop", retbins=True)
)

# where e.g.
labels_and_bins["A"][0]  # are the applied labels to all the rows in group "A"
labels_and_bins["A"][1]  # are the bin edges to apply the same segmentation going forward

for group in df.group.unique():
    df.loc[df["group"] == group, "value_label"] = labels_and_bins[group][0]
```

When I try to run this, at the second iteration I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot set a Categorical with another, without identical categories`

So, essentially I need Pandas to accept extending the categories belonging to the column dtype.

### What I have tried/considered

##### Transform

Using `.transform()` would probably solve the issue of assigning the label on the first DataFrame, but it's not clear to me how I could re-use the identified bins in future iterations

##### Unioning the categorical dtype

I tried two approaches:

**add_categories()**

`labels_and_bins['A'][0].cat.add_categories(labels_and_bins['B'][0].cat.as_unordered())`

This results in `ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique`

**union_categoricals()**

```py
pd.api.types.union_categoricals(
    [labels_and_bins["A"][0].cat.as_unordered(), labels_and_bins["B"][0].cat.as_unordered()].get_inde
)
```

This results in `InvalidIndexError: cannot handle overlapping indices; use IntervalIndex.get_indexer_non_unique`

### One solution

Get rid of the Interval object by calling qcut without labels, e.g.:

```py
labels_and_bins = df.groupby("group")["val"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q=5, duplicates="drop", retbins=True, labels=False)
)
```

However I would be interested in a way to keep the Interval if possible for better interpretability

---

**Overall this feels like a big anti-pattern, so I'm confident I'm missing a much more basic solution to this problem!**

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby(...).quantile` to get your bins. Getting the labels is the tricky part, if you want to have the same type of labels that `cut` and `qcut` returns you can convert this result to an `pandas.arrays.IntervalArray` and grab the left edges from there.

```py
bins = (
    df.groupby('group')['val']
    .quantile([0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1])

    # all of the below is to get those silly labels
    .groupby('group').apply(lambda s: 
        pd.Series(pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_breaks(s))
    )
    .to_frame('labels')
    .assign(breaks=lambda d: d['labels'].array.left)
)

print(bins)
                                           labels     breaks
group                                                       
A     0   (1.0537779249398262, 6.012235091686201]   1.053778
      1    (6.012235091686201, 8.290140550780626]   6.012235
      2   (8.290140550780626, 10.486391253124191]   8.290141
      3  (10.486391253124191, 14.187164706356482]  10.486391
      4   (14.187164706356482, 30.41871778451676]  14.187165
B     0   (-2.223397003597773, 2.929644956582803]  -2.223397
      1    (2.929644956582803, 4.205189382479166]   2.929645
      2    (4.205189382479166, 5.512744579486252]   4.205189
      3   (5.512744579486252, 6.9496607395781504]   5.512745
      4  (6.9496607395781504, 11.247907758459675]   6.949661

# Note that the 'labels' columns are not actually a bunch of strings,
#   but is a `Series` wrapped around the underlying `IntervalArray`
#   you can access the `IntervalArray` via the `.array` property
```

From here you can use `pd.merge_asof` to align your bins to other datasets or even back to your original `DataFrame`!

```py
# all of the sorting is required for `merge_asof`
result = pd.merge_asof(
    df.sort_values('val'), bins.sort_values('breaks'),
    left_on='val', right_on='breaks', by='group'
)

print(result.sample(8, random_state=0))
    group        val                                    labels     breaks
18      B   2.323406   (-2.223397003597773, 2.929644956582803]  -2.223397
170     A  12.238075  (10.486391253124191, 14.187164706356482]  10.486391
107     A   6.680556    (6.012235091686201, 8.290140550780626]   6.012235
98      A   6.499656    (6.012235091686201, 8.290140550780626]   6.012235
177     A  13.156868  (10.486391253124191, 14.187164706356482]  10.486391
182     A  14.734745   (14.187164706356482, 30.41871778451676]  14.187165
5       B   0.227872   (-2.223397003597773, 2.929644956582803]  -2.223397
146     A   9.562343   (8.290140550780626, 10.486391253124191]   8.290141
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could use chain for this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"group": "A", "val": np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=5, size=100)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"group": "B", "val": np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=3, size=100)})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

# apply qcut
labels_and_bins = df.groupby("group")["val"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q=5, duplicates="drop", retbins=True)
)

df['labels'] = list(chain.from_iterable([x[0].values for x in labels_and_bins]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like the idea of using `chain`, however a limitation of this result only holds when the df is ordered by group (acceptable as long as the ordering is consistent).

Answer (score 0):

I think tht what you are trying to achieve is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"group": "A", "val": np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=5, size=100)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"group": "B", "val": np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=3, size=100)})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

labels_and_bins = df.groupby("group")["val"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=5, duplicates="drop", retbins=True, labels=False)
)

bins = labels_and_bins.apply(lambda x: x[1])

for group in df.group.unique():
    df.loc[df["group"] == group, "value_label"] = pd.cut(
        df.loc[df["group"] == group, "val"], bins=bins[group], labels=False
    )

new_df = pd.DataFrame({"group": ["A", "B"], "val": [11, 3]})
for group in new_df.group.unique():
    new_df.loc[new_df["group"] == group, "value_label"] = pd.cut(
        new_df.loc[new_df["group"] == group, "val"], bins=bins[group]
    )

print(df)
print(new_df)
```

which give you your original df

```
    group        val  value_label
0       A  14.365754          3.0
1       A  10.620769          2.0
2       A  20.730151          4.0
3       A   0.947749          0.0
4       A   6.483682          2.0
..    ...        ...          ...
195     B  11.636778          4.0
196     B  12.288265          4.0
197     B   8.188767          3.0
198     B   7.419500          3.0
199     B   1.622162          1.0

[200 rows x 3 columns]
```

and the new one:

```
  group  val       value_label
0     A   11  (10.867, 15.798]
1     B    3    (1.512, 4.243]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If new_df has > 1 value per group however I do encounter the same issue.

e.g. with 
```new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
        "val": [11, 3, 10, 5, 3, 12,],
    }
)
for group in new_df.group.unique():
    new_df.loc[new_df["group"] == group, "value_label"] = pd.cut(
        new_df.loc[new_df["group"] == group, "val"], bins=bins[group]
    )```
(sorry for the horrible formatting...)